# Solving an ODE using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Here is my code. I do not understand why it does not work. Please help me.

```
NDSolve[
  {Derivative[1][x][t] == -x[t], 
   Derivative[1][y][t] == x[t] - y[t]^2, 
   Derivative[1][z][t] == y[t]*y[t], 
   y[0] == z[0] == 0, x[0] == 1}, 
  {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

The error I am seeing is:

> NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {True,True,True,True,True}.

Comment: Do `Clear[x, y, z, Derivative]` and try again.

Comment: Site tip: Searching the site for the message tag "deqn" turns up Q&A with the same error.